# How do I resize an image using javascript that is also being used with setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, image, resize, setinterval

I have searched and searched and cannot find an answer to my question. I am rotating the background image on a page I am trying to create. I was able to create the function to make the images change every 5 seconds but they are showing up very zoomed in.  I want it to fit the page and also be responsive.  I have tried adjusting it with CSS but it will override and no images show up. I saw people using canvas but in HTML.

I have included the javascript, css, and html I am using.

Thanks in advance.

```js
var images = [
    "/images/bar.jpg",
    "/images/bw.jpg",
    "/images/pilsner.jpg",
    "/images/pour.jpg",
    "/images/scene.jpg",
    "/images/scene.jpg",
    "/images/toast.jpg",
  ]
  
  var background = document.getElementById("background");
  var i = 0;
  
  setInterval(function() {
        background.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
        i = i + 1;
        if (i == images.length) {
            i =  0;
        } 
  }, 3000);
```

```css
.background{
    background-size: cover; 
}



#header{
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    <title>Wheres my ?</title>
  </head>
<body id="background">
    <script src="index.js"></script>

    <!-- Image and text -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="header">
        <div class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Dude, where's my beer?</div>
        <span class="navbar-text">
           Helping you find your favorite beers.
        </span>
    </nav>
   
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: set the css width and/or height

Comment: There is a mistake in the css selector: you use class selector .background instead of id selector #background. And probably you also would like to add background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: Thanks mcm, I didn't notice that. Again small typing errors got me. I had been working on code all day long at that point.